# Avoid abnormally long space in table using split

Tags: longtable, split

sorry about uploading this again. There is a lot of whitespace in the output for in the second column when I split my first column. Is there any way I can get rid of that? This is my MWE. I want to get rid of the whitespace shown in the picture.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \newcommand{\mysplit}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}@{}@{}}   %% removed [t]
  #1
   \end{tabular}
    }

\begin{longtable}{lp{10cm}} 
    \caption{Candidate Genes}\\
    \toprule
    Candidate Gene & Gene function\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead 
    \toprule
    Candidate Gene & Gene function\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \mysplit{XXXXX\\ XXXXX\\ XXXXX\\ XXXXX\\ XXXXX\\ } & Functions as cell adhesion molecules and receptors in the CNS. Mediate neurotransmitter release by linking Calcium channels to synaptic vesicle exocytosis. Disruption associated with ASD characterised by seizures and communication deficits \\ 
        \mysplit{XXXXXXXXXXX\\ XXXXX\\ XXXXX} & interact as ligands with neurexins expressed in presynaptic neurons. Clinical phenotype is heterogeneous, and mutation carrier undergo regression at disease onset, characterised by loss of acquired social and verbal milestones\\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX,   & A transcriptional repressor that binds to methylated CpG dinucleotides \\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX,  & Necessary for proper development of brainstem, cerebellum, inner ear  \\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX,  &  A tumour suppressor gene influencing G1 cell cycle arrest and apoptosis.  \\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX, &  implicated in patterns formation during development\\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX, & One part of 13 subunit ligand gated chloride channel\\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX, &  Instrumental in cell adhesion as well as cell surface-mediated signalling.\\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX,  & Pleiotropic receptor with tyrosine kinase activity\\ 
        XXXXXXXXXXX, &  G-protein coupled receptor that binds to Oxytocin \\
        XXXXXXXXXXX, & Large secreted extracellular matrix protein\\
        XXXXXXXXXXX, &  Integral membrane protein\\
    \\\bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Need to get rid of the whitespace in the second column]

Comment: as your comment shows `%% removed [t]` so the tabular is not top aligned so the centre of the tabular aligns with the first line in the `p` column.

Comment: Thank you. It still has a lot of whitespace though, is there a way I can get the second column in the middle. I'll modify the code and upload the new picture I have now

Comment: no, it is not. if i consider @DavidCarlisle comment, i.e. use ` \newcommand{\mysplit}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}   %% removed [t]
  #1
   \end{tabular}
    }
` I can't confirm your claims. there is no more a white space

Comment: not sure what you changed, but my earlier comment still applies, you have vertically centred table and a top aligned paragraph column. which is why the baseline of `Functions as cel...` is aligned with the centre of your tabular. use `[t]` where the comment says `[t]` is not used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I didn't change anything. I fixed the excessive whitespace I had in a lengthy description by adding another \\ line to the description. Also I had more entries on the other column as well, for that particular thing. So, my bad. It was not a code thing, it was the way I'd set my table. Thank you again

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  It looks like all you want to do is place a list of (redacted) names next to a long paragraph, with occasional breaks to align things.  There are easier ways to do that.

Comment: I think the way David told me was quite easy, but I'm happy to hear any suggestions you have.